# Evento hover no funciona despúes de una llamada al servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Muy buenas !

Estoy realizando una web y me ha surgido que después de hacer una llamada al servidor para listar imágenes, el evento hover del script no se ejecuta más, puede que pierda especificidad, lo que intento hacer es generar un background con colores random.

Dejo una parte de lo que estoy editando por si me pueden ayudar, muchas gracias

```
$.post( ruta, function( data ) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

        for (var index = 0; index < obj.length; index++) {
              var id = obj[index].id;
              var album_name = obj[index].album_name;
              var album_description = obj[index].album_description;
              var url_image = "images/"+obj[index].url_image;
              var image = obj[index].image;

              var newLi = $(document.createElement('li'));
              newLi.addClass("container-imagen-miniatura");

              var liClass = '<div class="images">'+
                                '<a href="girls-wagmag.php" >'+
                                '<img src="'+ url_image+'" alt="tree" class="imagen-miniatura">'+
                                '<div class="middle">'+
                                '<div class="descripcion"> </div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<i class="fa fa-search lupa" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+
                                '</a>'+
                                '</div>';



              newLi.after().html(liClass);
              newLi.appendTo('#grid-images ul');
        } 
  });
});

  </script>
  <script>
        $("#grid-images .images .middle").hover(function () {
              $("#grid-images ul li .images a:hover .middle").css({ opacity: 0.4});

              var back = ["blue","gray","#0ECB0E","#E9FF00","#FDAC11","#FD1711","#CB0E79","#6417AB","#1F3BAC", "#0B9F8A","#30D30E","#55ce96"];
              var rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
              $("#grid-images ul li .images a:hover .middle").css("background",rand);
            }, function(){
            $(".middle").css("background","transparent");
            $(".middle").css("opacity",0);
          } );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando generas codigo dinamicamente, jquery no puede capturar los eventos de esos nuevos elementos del DOM. 
Tenes que usar esta funcion especial de jquery.

> ```
> $('.images .middle').on("hover","#grid-images",function(event){
> //Bloque de codigo
> });
> ```